# Nested comment thread - recursive rendering in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion, view, comments

I am trying to create a question and answer thread in Rails 6  where a User can answer on a question, and then other users can comment on the answer - similar to a reddit or even stackoverflow.

I created a polymorphic association on my Answer model with a 'parent_id' and I am able to post answers on the initial question. However the nested answers do not render below the initial answer, but rather below the main question. I think I have isolated the problem to the corresponding partial view seen below:

**Answer View**

```
<li>
<%= answer.body %></br>
<%= link_to answer.user.first_name, answer.user %> 
<%= link_to answer.user.last_name, answer.user %> 
answered <%= time_ago_in_words(answer.created_at) %> ago.

<div class="comments-container">
<%= render partial: "answers/reply", locals: {commentable: answer.commentable, parent_id: answer.parent.id} %>  
</div>

<ul> <%= render partial: "answers/answer", collection: answer.answers %> </ul>
 </li>
```

From my understanding, the last line should render the answers to the answer, however the answers render underneath the initial question, and not the answer. Any ideas on what im doing wrong?
Should I be using a gem like [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) to do this? If so how would that work?

For completeness, here are the other components

**Question View**

```
<h3><%= @question.title %></h3>
<p> Asked by <%= link_to @question.user.email, @question.user %> <%= time_ago_in_words(@question.created_at) %> ago. </p>
</br>
<span class="body"> <%= @question.body %> </span>
</br>

<h5><strong><%= @question.answers.count %> Answers</strong></h5>

<%= render @answers %></br>
<%= render partial: "answers/form", locals: {commentable: @question} %> </br>
<%= paginate @answers %>
```

**Answer model**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :parent, optional: true, class_name: 'Answer'
belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
has_many :answers, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
validates :body, presence: true 
validates :user, presence: true
```

**Question model**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :answers, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
validates :body, presence: true
validates :title, presence: true
validates :user, presence: true
```

**AnswerController**

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_answer, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote, :downvote]
before_action :find_commentable, only: [:create]

def new
  @answer = Answer.new
end

def create
  @answer = @commentable.answers.new(answer_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @answer.save
      format.html { redirect_to @commentable }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @commentable }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def destroy
  @answer = @commentable.answers.find(params[:id])
  @answer.discard
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @commentable, notice: 'Answer was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
def set_answer
  @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
end

def answer_params
  params.require(:answer).permit(:body).merge(user_id: current_user.id, parent_id: params[:parent_id])
end

def find_commentable
  @commentable = Answer.find(params[:answer_id]) if params[:answer_id]
  @commentable = Question.find(params[:question_id]) if params[:question_id]
end

end
```

**Question Controller**

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote, :downvote]

def index
  @questions = Question.order('created_at desc').page(params[:page])
end

def show
  @answer = @question.answers.new  
  @answers = if params[:answer]
             @question.answers.where(id: params[:answer])
             else
             @question.answers.where(parent_id: nil)
             end

  @answers = @answers.page(params[:page]).per(5)
end

def new
  @question = Question.new
end

def edit
end

def create
  @question = Question.new(question_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @question.save
      format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'You have successfully asked a question!' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @question }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @question.update(question_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @question }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def destroy
  @question.discard
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @questions_url, notice: 'Question successfully deleted.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private

def set_question
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
end

def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(:title, :body, :tag_list).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end

end
```

Comment: The rendering of the partial looks ok but you don't need to be so verbose `<%= render answer.answers %>` will do the exact same thing. Are you sure that its not due to malformed html or a CSS issue? Check the html source (not just the rendered DOM in the web inspector).

Comment: Okay, i've cleaned up the code to be less verbose and complicated as suggested. The html source also renders incorrectly, witih the reply to an answer just rendering at the very bottom. I don't think it should be a CSS issue as I haven't done anything fancy on that end yet. Mostly just been focusing on the backend

Comment: You probably want to backstep a bit and rethink the general approach though. Basicially for every recursive iteration you're going to be creating a N+1 query. Add together the number of answers and subanswers and its going to be a really slow even with pagination. I added an answer that doesn't solve the view issue (which really shouldn't be your biggest concern right now) but addresses the database design  aspect.

Comment: Yeah that is what i've figured. Ive tried different approaches, mainly using gems, but they ran into the same View issues. Which is why I tried to do it 'manually'. Initially I didn't use a polymorphic approach, but I saw some others using it, so I figured I would give it a try to see if it would fix the rendering. 

In any case, it appears that what i've built won't work, so will have to start from scratch. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem with using gems like ancestry is that it abstracts away so much that you won't learn how to setup a tree with a self-referential association so doing it yourself can actually be a good idea. In this case it would be a lot easier conceptually if you used three tables `questions` -> `answers` -> `comments` which would remove the need for polymorphism or STI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You kind of failed at modeling polymorphism. If you want a true polymorphic association you would model it as so:

```
class Question
  has_many :answers, as: :answerable
end

class Answer
  belongs_to :answerable, polymorphic: true 
  has_many :answers, as: :answerable
end
```

This lets the "parent" of a question be either a Question or a Answer and you don't need to do ridiculous stuff like `@question.answers.where(parent_id: nil)`. You can just do `@answers = @question.answers` and this will only include the first generation children.

However polymorphism isn't all its cracked up to be and that will be especially apparent when building a tree hierarchy. Since we actually have to pull the rows out of the database to know where to join you can't eager load the tree effectively. Polymorphism is mainly useful if the number of parent classes in large or unknown or you're just prototyping.

Instead you can use Single Table Inheritance to setup the associations:

```
class CreateAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :answers do |t|
      t.string :type
      t.belongs_to :question, null: true, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :answer, null: true, foreign_key: true
      # ... more columns
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Note the nullable foreign key columns. Unlike with polymophism these are real foreign keys so the db will ensure referential integrity. Also note the `type` column which has a special significance in ActiveRecord.

Then lets setup the models:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :answers, class_name: 'Questions::Answer'
end

class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :answers, class_name: 'Answers::Answer'
end
```

And the subclasses of Answer:

```
# app/models/answers/answer.rb
module Answer
  class Answer < ::Answer
    belongs_to :answer
    has_one :question, through: :answer
  end
end

# app/models/questions/answer.rb
module Questions
  class Answer < ::Answer
    belongs_to :question
  end
end
```

Pretty cool. Now we can eager load to the first and second generation with:

```
Question.eager_load(answers: :anser)
```

And we can keep going:

```
Question.eager_load(answers: { answers: :answer })
Question.eager_load(answers: { answers: { answers: :answers }})
```

But at some point you'll want to call it quits and start using ajax like reddit does.

Comment: I guess the main issue with my polymorphic approach was the use of `belongs_to :parent, optional: true, class_name: 'Answer'`, which I used to see if I could explicitly call one or the other. I introduced the code in the controller initially as a test to see if my code was working as intended. 

This approach with subclasses seems like it should be a more efficient way of modelling this though. Thanks for your help, ill see how far I can get with it